# JSON file Download from Server , file is loaded 8 times?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am loading my LiveRatingDemo.json from the internet server.
Everything works but,
The LiveRatingDemo.json is loaded 8 times from the server why?
What have I forgotten or done wrong?

my LiveRatingDemo.json :

```
{
    "ratingArray":[{
        "ratingClubID":"101",
        "ratingValue":"2"
    },
    {
        "ratingClubID":"102",
        "ratingValue":"4"
    },
    {
        "ratingClubID":"103",
        "ratingValue":"5"
    },
    {
        "ratingClubID":"104",
        "ratingValue":"1"
    },
    {
        "ratingClubID":"105",
        "ratingValue":"3"
    },
    {
        "ratingClubID":"106",
        "ratingValue":"5"
    },
    {
        "ratingClubID":"107",
        "ratingValue":"4"
    }
    ]
}
```

my objective c Code :

```
-(void)parseLiveRating
{


    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:getLiveRating];
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"LiveRatingDemo.json"];

    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    [manager GET:path parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id JSON)
     {
         NSDictionary *dictTemp = (NSDictionary *) JSON;
         NSArray *arrRating = [dictTemp objectForKey:@"ratingArray"];
         NSLog(@"Test Ausgabe : %@", arrRating);

         for (int i=0; i<arrRating.count; i++) {
             GetRating *rat = [[GetRating alloc] init];
             [rat parseResponse:[arrRating objectAtIndex:i]];
             [mratingLive addObject:rat];

             NSLog(@"Success: %@", JSON);

             [self displayAllRatings];
         }


     } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {

         NSLog(@"Error Loading: %@", error);

     }];

}
```

Thank you for your efforts

Comment: You log `NSLog(@"Success: %@", JSON);` INSIDE the for loop. If visually you really have 8 times the data, could you share the code of `displayAllRatings`? Does it copy from `mRatingLive`?

Comment: -(void)displayAllRatings 
{
    for (int i=0; i<mratingLive.count; i++) {
        GetRating *rat = [mratingLive objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Rating Club ID : %@ Rating Value %@", rat.ratingClubID , rat.ratingValue);
    }
}

Comment: @Phil_Austria Where do you call `parseLiveRating`?

Comment: from "viewDidLoad"

Comment: @Phil_Austria Can you share value of `dictTemp`?

Comment: Move `NSLog(@"Success: %@", JSON);` before the for loop and `[self displayAllRatings];` after the for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I give you the solution.From your question you asked

**The LiveRatingDemo.json is loaded 8 times from the server why?**

The First Reason is

> 1.You added or put NSLog(@"Success: %@", JSON) code in for loop.Whenever for loop runs,it prints the result.If you have 8
>   objects,eight times it prints or displays the result.
>   So you need to remove the NSLog(@"Success: %@", JSON) from the for loop.

The Second Reason is

> 2.Then you must remove the [self displayAllRatings] line from the for loop.Becuase I think in [self displayAllRatings] you call the
>   mratingLive array.So every time that method calls when for loop runs.
>
> Just call that method out of the for loop.